# Spring 3 integration testing - sessionFactory inicialization exception

Tags: hibernate, persistence, sessionfactory, spring-test

When i run my spring junit test i got this error message :

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
```

....

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE074 no Code attribute specified; class=javax/persistence/PersistenceException, method=<init>()V, pc=0
```

*Could you help me to find a reason for that error message ? Seems i have some problems with dependencies of slf4j - but i have them in the project.*

**Test class :**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/businessApplicationContextTest.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional
public class LogicHandlerTest {

    @SessionFactory
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Before
public void setup() {System.out.println("@Before");}

@Test
public void testDummy() {
    System.out.println("testDummy");
    assert(true);
}
}
```

**Spring test context configuration :**

```
<!-- DATASOURCE -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"    value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>       
    <property name="url"                value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test"/>        
    <property name="username"           value="sa"/>          
    <property name="password"           value=""/>  
</bean> 

<!-- SESSION FACTORY -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.dummyproject.entity"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- TRANSACTION MANAGER -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

DEPENDENCIES (versions from POM.XML) :

```
    hibernate                        3.2.3.ga
    hibernate-annotations            3.3.1.GA
    hibernate-commons-annotations    3.2.0.Final
    javaee-api                   6.0
    slf4j-api                        1.6.4
    slf4j-log4j12                    1.6.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for that error message was mess in maven dependencies - i ve removed javaee 6 dependency from my project and everything works fine now. (Because websphere server already contain javaee 6 library).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not injecting SessionFactory in your Test,

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" auto-wire="byName">

@Resource
SessionFactory sessionFactory
```

update: add these jars in your classpath

```
01.antlr-2.7.6
02.commons-collections-3.1
03.dom4j-1.6.1
04.hibernate3
05.database specific jar
06.javassist-3.4.GA
07.jta-1.1
08.slf4j-api-1.5.6
09.slf4j-simple-1.5.6
```

Comment: I added SessionFactory into it and now i see : 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;  Which propebly means i have some dependancy hierarchy confict... :(

Comment: i added all the jars which are required.